# onItemClick() receives layout instead of TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-constraintlayout, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView in my Activity whose rows are populated by logins fetched from a database. Each row in my ListView contains one TextView inside a Constraint Layout. When user touches one of the rows of this ListView, another activity should be launched. I used OnItemClickListener to achieve this and everything seems to work fine, but onClickItem() method from Listener receives a reference to object of type ConstraintLayout and I need to obtain text from TextView inside this layout. How can I do this?

Here is my xml of a simple row:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my implementation of OnItemClickListener:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView currentView = (TextView) view; // Here I get an exception that ConstraintLayout cannot be casted to TextView
            String login = currentView.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Powitanie.this,UserPanel.class);
            intent.putExtra(LOGIN, login);
            Powitanie.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

Comment: `(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row)`, though you really shouldn't be pulling data from `View`s like that. Just get it from the dataset you passed to the `Adapter`.

Comment: @Mike M. First solution doesn't work for me. Listener passes wrong login to next activity. And I don't understand the second solution. Should I create SimpleCursorAdapter inside onClickItem() method?

Comment: The first suggestion was to solve the `ClassCastException`. I have no idea what your actual data or design is. If you're using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` for the `ListView`, then you have a `Cursor` that you can pull the data from. The third parameter in `onItemClick()` is the item's position. You can `cursor.moveToPosition(i)`, and then `cursor.getString(???)` to get the value from whichever column it's in, substituting the appropriate column index for `???`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *getChildAt()* method. onItemClick() receives reference to a view. We can cast it to ConstraintLayout and get a child from a specified index.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) view;
            TextView currentView = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0); // In getChildAt we need to specify index of a child. In this case it's 0.
            String login = currentView.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Powitanie.this,UserPanel.class);
            intent.putExtra(LOGIN, login);
            Powitanie.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```